# how can I get line messenger api (bot) access token and refresh token

Tags: node.js

https://devdocs.line.me/en/#reissuing-access-tokens

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {ENTER_ACCESS_TOKEN}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d 'refreshToken=123ab456cdef8910ghu' \
```

https://api.line.me/v1/oauth/accessToken

in the above curl command there is a refresh token specified.... how can I get the refresh token of line bot?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the access token and refresh token by logging in line.

You can find the related documentation here, https://developers.line.me/web-api/integrating-web-login#obtain_access_token

For refresh token you have to send an **post** request to

```
https://api.line.me/v1/oauth/accessToken

Name            Type    Description
grant_type      String  Fixed “authorization_code”.
client_id       String  Channel ID.
client_secret   String  Channel Secret string issued when registering your Channel.
code            String  Acquired authorization code.
redirect_uri    String  Callback URL string passed at issuing the authorization code.
```

And you will get the token in response

```
Property         Type   Description
mid              String     ID of authorized user
access_token     String     Access token string
expires_in       Integer    Validity of access token. Elapsed time in seconds from when the access token is issued.
refresh_token    String     Token string necessary to reissue (refresh) a new access token
scope   —   Fixed null value
```

Comment: we would like to use messaging api to send messages. we can see how to validate an access token over here https://devdocs.line.me/en/#validating-the-access-token but not sure how to get the refresh_token to extend the validity of current access token

Comment: Please see the edited answer. I hope you can get the client id and secret and set the redirect url by sign up for business center of line and set up the messaging  api details.

Comment: i can't get the authorization code https://developers.line.me/web-api/integrating-web-login#obtain_request_token in here i can't login.user id and password is correct... but it shows..."Sorry. There were problems logging you in. 
Please wait a while before trying again."

Comment: Did you get the correct 
    Channel ID
    Channel secret
    Callback URL
and send all parameter with the request?

Comment: We were able to create a bot and get its access token as described here https://developers.line.me/messaging-api/getting-started. We cant find any redirect uri to be specified for the BOT. We have got the acess token from "basic information"  of the bot. There is no refresh token specifed there. Where can we get a refresh token for extending the time frame of access token